# XFS Realtime (CONFIG_XFS_RT), Is it really usefull for high i/o servers?

Tags: linux, filesystems, xfs

Recently we got more crashes and i/o errors from XFS filesystem. The reason what we thinks about it because of high disk i/o. We are uploading several GB's of data and deleting per week for big data purpose. 
So while reading XFS documents i found "XFS realtime" option and they mention specifically that, its for realtime streaming purpose. 
For that i recompiled my CentOS machine with CONFIG_XFS_RT and created 3 partitions for log, data and realtime.
Still i am confused about XFS realtime.
Can any one help me to figure out what is XFS realtime and is that really helps heavy i/o servers?

Comment: High disk I/O should never result in crashes and I/O errors (what does that mean exactly in your case?) . You need to find out what is the cause of this, and, fundamentally, what kind of problem you really have, as you don't seem to know this. Blindly trying some config option you don't understand to solve a problem you don't understand isn't helpful.

Comment: That said, the RT option would likely not help for an I/O saturated server because it can't create more I/O throughput - it's meant to make sure that things like video streams that come at a predicable and semi-constant rate can be written to disk in a timely manner. This is likely not your problem...

Answer (score -1):

So per my understanding if you are using XFS for hadoop you should disable all additional filesystem parameters because it wouldn't worth it and give more overhead for hadoop like atime, noatime, also it depend on workload too such as  large files without small inode clusters or small file and large inode.
Hope it will help.